# $(2^k-1)/k$ is approximately equal to $n/\log n$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, integers

Let k be the greates integer such that $2^k+k-2 \leq n$ (where also n is an integer). In this hypothesis $(2^k-1)/k$ is approximately equal to $n/\log n$. [For example it is always between $n/2\log n $ and $n/\log n$].

I cannot convince myself of the above statement. I tried some calculations but they didn't work out.

P.s: $\log$ is the log base 2.

Comment: I also tried some calculations, but they didn't work out.

Comment: No reason to confine this to integers. $f(x)=2^x+x-2$ is a continuous increasing function so d$f^{-1}$ exists, and you are seeking estimates for $f^{-1}(n).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews doesn't seem that easy to me...

Comment: $$\frac{2^{f^{-1}(x)}-1}{f^{-1}(x)}=\frac{x-f^{-1}(x)+1}{f^{-1}(x)}=\frac{x}{f^{-1}(x)}+O(1)$$
So you need to show $f^{-1}(x)\approx \log_2x$ with a "good enough" error.

Comment: For $x>2,$ at least, $f^{-1}(x)<\log_2x.$ So you need a lower bound.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't get what are you doing in the first line, why are you substituing $k$ with $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: Because $$k=\lfloor f^{-1}(n)\rfloor =f^{-1}(n)+O(1).$$ @Cristie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An ugly approach.** Clearly, $2^k \leq n$, so since $f$ defined on $[1,\infty)$ by $f(x)=(x-1)/\log_2(x)$ (and $f(1)=\ln 2$) is increasing, you get
$$
\frac{2^k-1}{k} \leq \frac{n-1}{\log_2 n} < \frac{n}{\log_2 n}
$$
(as long as $n\geq 2$ at least).

For the lower bound, by definition of $k=k(n)$ we have
$
2^{k+1}+k-1 > n
$
and in particular, since $k \leq 2^{k+1}$,
$$
2\cdot 2^{k+1} > n
$$
Using the same property of $f$, we get
$$
\frac{n-1}{\log_2 n}<\frac{2^{k+2}-1}{k+2}
$$
which implies  (as $n-1 \geq n/2$)
$$
\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}<\frac{2^{k+2}-1}{k+2}
<\frac{2^{k+2}-1}{k} = 4\cdot\frac{2^{k}-1/4}{k} \leq 8\cdot\frac{2^{k}-1}{k}
$$
at the end using $x-1/4 \leq 2(x-1)$ for $x\geq 2$. That gives
$$
\frac{n}{16\log_2 n} \leq \frac{2^{k}-1}{k} \leq \frac{n}{\log_2 n}
$$

Comment: I think you should state that f(2) = 1, right?

Comment: Good catch -- it should be $f(1)=\ln 2$. (Defined by continuity, but I messed up the base of the log.)

Comment: However I don't get how you are doing the first inequality... I can see that $(2^k-1)/k \leq (n-1)/k$ but how can you estimate the $k$ in the denominator with $(n-1)$?

Comment: Since $2^k \leq n$, $\frac{2^k-1}{k} = f(2^k) \leq  f(n) = \frac{n-1}{\log_2 n}$

Comment: That is! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad this helped!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148189/discussion-between-cristie-and-clement-c).

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts**.

**Fact 1**: Let $n\ge 2$ be an integer.
Let $k$ be the greatest integer such that $2^k + k - 2 \le n$. Then
$$\frac12 \cdot \frac{n\ln 2}{\ln n} \le \frac{2^k - 1}{k} \le \frac{n\ln 2}{\ln n}. \tag{1}$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

*Note*: The constant $\frac12$ is best in this sense. When $n = 2^m$ for integer $m\ge 3$,
we have $k = m-1$ and
$$\frac{\frac{2^k - 1}{k}}{\frac{n\ln 2}{\ln n} } = \frac{(2^{m-1} - 1)m}{2^m(m - 1)} \to \frac12, \quad \mathrm{as}\ m \to \infty.$$

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*:

**For the right inequality**:

For $n = 2, 3$, the desired inequality is directly verified.

In the following, assume that $n \ge 4$.

Let $m := \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}$.

We have $2^m + m - 2 - n = \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} - 2 \ge 0$. Thus, $k \le m$.

Note that $x \to \frac{2^x - 1}{x}$ is strictly increasing on $x > 0$. Thus, we have
$$\frac{n\ln 2}{\ln n} - \frac{2^k -  1}{k}
\ge \frac{n\ln 2}{\ln n} - \frac{2^m - 1}{m}
= \frac{\ln 2}{\ln n} > 0.$$

$\phantom{2}$

**For the left inequality**:

For $n = 2, 3, \cdots, 19$, the desired inequality is directly verified.

In the following, assume that $n \ge 20$.

Let $ s:= \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n}$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 2^s + s - 2 - n &= \frac{n}{2} \cdot 2^{1-\frac{5}{4\sqrt n}}
 + \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n} - 2 - n\\
 &\le \frac{n}{2} \cdot \left(1 + 1 - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n}\right)
 + \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n} - 2 - n\\
 &= - \frac58\sqrt n + \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n} - 2\\
 &< - \frac58\sqrt n + \frac{\ln n}{\ln 2} - 2\\ 
 &< 0
\end{align*}
where we use the Bernoulli inequality
to obtain $2^{1-\frac{5}{4\sqrt n}} = (1 + 1)^{1-\frac{5}{4\sqrt n}}
\le 1 + 1 - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n}$.

Thus, we have $k \ge s - 1$.

Note that $x \to \frac{2^x - 1}{x}$ is strictly increasing on $x > 0$. It suffices to prove that
$$
  \frac{2^{s-1} - 1}{s - 1} - \frac12 \cdot \frac{n\ln 2}{\ln n} \ge 0
$$
or
$$2^{-\frac{5}{4\sqrt n}} - \frac{2}{n}
- 1 + \left(\frac{5}{4\sqrt n} + 1\right)\frac{\ln 2}{\ln n} \ge 0.$$

Using $\mathrm{e}^u \ge 1 + u$ for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$2^{-\frac{5}{4\sqrt n}} = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{5}{4\sqrt n}\ln 2}
\ge 1 - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n}\ln 2$.

It suffices to prove that
$$1 - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n}\ln 2 - \frac{2}{n}
- 1 + \left(\frac{5}{4\sqrt n} + 1\right)\frac{\ln 2}{\ln n} \ge 0$$
or
$$ - \frac{5}{4\sqrt n}\ln 2 - \frac{2}{n}
 + \left(\frac{5}{4\sqrt n} + 1\right)\frac{\ln 2}{\ln n} \ge 0.$$
This inequality is true.